# Grails equivelant of Rails ARel 'includes'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grails, grails-orm, arel

I have a Rails app that I was able to speed up significantly using ARel "includes" e.g. (contrived)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :posts
   scope :eager, includes(:posts => [:rating, :author, {:tags => [:day, {:foo => :bar}]}] )
end
```

Calling

```
@posts = current_user.posts.eager
```

reduces that page load hugely and reduces the number queries by a very large factor. Rails does this by first selecting the posts in one query

```
select * from posts where ...
```

and then selecting all the comments for all those posts in one query instead of one query per comment:

```
select * from comments where post_id in (6,7,8,9,10,...)
```

Is there an equivalent in grails? I am familiar with criteria and named queries where  I could write a query with a lot of joins but what I want is for Grails to produce a few queries with "IN" operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some references to this problem: [Eager and Lazy Fetching](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#fetching) and [fetchMode](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/fetchMode.html).

Comment: I think this goes some of the way but for my example above it would have a separate query for all comments on each post but I was hoping for a single query for all comment for all posts.